# Should a focus trap prevent a user from reaching the context UI like e.g. the browser?

Tags: modal-dialog, focus, accessibility

When we trap the focus inside a modal, should the focus cycle within the modal or should a user be able to reach the outside, like let's say the browser UI?

It's not clear from the official specifications for the web: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#dialog_modal

At least in an example provided by said specifications, it's actually like so, that you are not able to reach anything but focusable elements in the modal: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html

This comes with side-effects like breaking the developer tools:
[image: a screenshot showing how the tab index toggle still displays the browser UI as reachable]
Here's a video for further clarification: https://streamable.com/i4zcsp

Comment: In the first link, under **Keyboard Interaction** section, it says "If focus is on the last tabbable element inside the dialog, moves focus to the first tabbable element inside the dialog.". Plus, I have seen a lot of front-end libraries implement the same (like [antd](https://ant.design/components/modal/)). So **YES**, focus should get trapped inside the modal.

Comment: @TylerDurden True, missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question! My short answer is: It should not allow to <kbd>tab</kbd> outside the modal.

Long answer:

> Like non-modal dialogs, modal dialogs contain their tab sequence. That is, Tab and Shift + Tab do not move focus outside the dialog. However, unlike most non-modal dialogs, modal dialogs do not provide means for moving keyboard focus outside the dialog window without closing the dialog.

This leads to two things:

1. <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> are trapped. Reaching the last (first) element will move the focus to the other end.
2. You have „means for moving keyboard focus outside the dialog”. But then, you must close the dialog.

So when you register a key event listener (and handle <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the dialog and restore focus), you should also handle the mentioned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for reaching the URL bar (resp. Awesome Bar) and perhaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for the search bar.

Find more keyboard shortcuts for

- [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly)
- [Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179)
- [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/keyboard-access/)
- [Edge](https://defkey.com/microsoft-edge-chromium-shortcuts)
- [Opera](https://help.opera.com/en/latest/shortcuts/)
- [Safari](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/cpsh003/mac)

Given the variety, you might want to dismiss the modal on everything that was not handled inside. User tests would give you a hint on what people expect.

Regarding the developer tools: Opening them in another window might do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You are only responsible for trapping the focus **within the content**.  That is, anything that is HTML.  You don't have to worry about the user moving the focus to other interactive elements that are part of the browser itself.

I often have several tabs open in my browser, looking at different websites.  If one of those pages happened to have a dialog open that was trapping the keyboard focus, I would **not** want my focus to be trapped such that I couldn't get my focus on the browser's tab panel and switch to another tab.  Nor would I want the focus trapped so that I couldn't get to the browser's main menu (File, Edit, View, etc).  Nor would I want the focus trapped so that I couldn't get to the browser's address bar (<kbd>alt+D</kbd> or <kbd>cmd+L</kbd>).

One minor nuance in your OP.  You mentioned the "official spec" for dialogs.  There really isn't an "official" spec with regards to a normative language for a dialog.  The "WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices" that you refer to is a fantastic resource and should be followed as much as possible, but *not* following it does not mean you aren't WCAG conformant.  Notice in section "[1. Introduction](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#intro)", the first thing it says is:

> This section is *informative*.

You can see definitions of [informative](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#dfn-informative) and [normative](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#dfn-normative). In particular:

> Content identified as "informative" or "non-normative" is never required for conformance.

Comment: Thanks @AradAlvand. The accepted answer has good info too. I'm not competing for points in trying to get accepted answers. I just provide info about accessibility to share with others.